WooCommerce Dynamic Bundle Product
I have a WooCommerce store which contains 2 categories:

Category A (7 products)
Category B (10 products)

I want to make a bundle product, but to be somehow dynamically.
- For example:
When you access the bundle product which would be priced 99 EUR, to have option (must choose) at least 2 "Category A" products, and at least 10 "Category B" products
Product from the categories could repeat until the threshold is reached.
Cart product bundle should look like:

Product #5A - qty 1
Product #6A - qty 1
Product #3B - qty 5
Product #5B - qty 3
Product #9B - qty 2

I have access to a couple of product bundle plugins , like official one from WooCommerce or YITH pro version, but don't know how to achieve this type of scenario.
